# pointers in c not getting correct output

Tags: c, pointers

Im trying to make a program with 3 functions called getnumber(ask for number) findlargest(find largest between 2 numbers) and displaylargest that shows which one was larger. I am new to pointers and when I enter 2 numbers no matter if the first number is larger it always says the second number is larger can someone tell me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float getnumbers();
float findlargest(float*,float*);
void displaylargest(float,float*,float*);

int main ()
{
    float num1;
    float num2;
    float largest;

    num1=getnumbers();
    num2=getnumbers();

    largest=findlargest(&num1,&num2);

    displaylargest(largest,&num1,&num2);
    return 0;
}

float getnumbers()
{
    float num;
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%2f",&num);
    return num;
}


float findlargest(float*num1ptr,float*num2ptr)
{
    float num1;
    float num2;

    *num1ptr=num1;
    *num2ptr=num2;

    if (num1>num2) {
        return num1;
    } else {
        return num2;
    }
}

void displaylargest(float largest,float*num1ptr,float*num2ptr)
{
    printf("\nthe largest is %2f ",largest);
}
```

Comment: please properly format your code.

Comment: May I ask why you are using pointers? That's completely unnecessary for writing a function to get the maximum value. Just write it as `float findLargest(float a, float b) { if (a>b) return a; else return b; }`

Comment: `*num1ptr=num1;*num2ptr=num2;` is undefined behavior, you are reading uninitialized variables.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya It is not *undefined behavior*. It is just a bit unpredictable. There's a difference.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: thanks it was for a slight intro to pointers for an extra class im taking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a mistake while typing instead of assigning `num1=*num1ptr` you did `*nump1tr=num1` and same for `num2` your code should be like

```
float findlargest(float*num1ptr,float*num2ptr)
{
  float num1;
  float num2;

  num1=*num1ptr; // not *num1ptr=num1
  num2=*num2ptr; // not *num2ptr=num2

  if (num1>num2) {
      return num1;
    } 
  else {
      return num2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring  `float num1;` and `float num2;`, but you never assign them any value, so they will contain some random number that happens to be in your computer’s memory. Then you check `if (num1>num2)`, based on these random values.

Chances are that you get the same ‘random’ values every time you run it, as the computer has no reason to ever change that place in memory, so the result will always be the same.

You need to assign the values the other way round: `num1=*numptr1;` (or use the parameters directly in the comparison - there is no reason to copy them around).

Answer (score 0):

```
float findlargest(float *num1ptr, float *num2ptr)
{
    float num1;
    float num2;

    *num1ptr = num1;
    *num2ptr = num2;
```

This does *not* do what you (apparently) think it does. Declaring `num1` and `num2` here sets them to arbitrary values which you then use to *overwrite* whatever useful data you may have had in the variables pointed to by `num1ptr` and `num2ptr`.

A better variant would simply be:

```
float findLargest(float num1, float num2)
{
    if (num1 > num2)
        return num1;
    return num2;
}
```

and then just call it with (from `main`):

```
printf("The largest is %.2f\n", findLargest(num1, num2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your first condition `if(num1 > num2)` this is unlikely to be true, so you can't expect an specific value. Why it is like that? Because you're doing `*ptr = value;` assignment where you're intended to do `value = *ptr;`, and since you didn't initialized `num1` and `num2` they will have unspecified values.

For methods like this you can use ternary/conditional operator `return condition ? trueValue : falseValue;` so:

```
float largest(float a, float b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

You shouldn't use pointers where you don't need it, it makes your code more complex unnecessarily.

How did you even identified the problem?

Comment: Well. Since both `num1` and `num2` are uninitialized it is not unlikely that `(num1 > num2)` is true. Otherwise I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: Tbh I would simply comment the question but I need 50 reputation to do that. This comment is mostly to let others know that the conditional operator can help them to write simpler methods. By the way, edited, I think it's "better" now.

Answer (score 0):

// Try this

## include < stdio.h> // remove the space

float getnumbers();

float findlargest(float*,float*);

void displaylargest(float); // one parameter is enough in this function

int main ()
{

```
float num1;

float num2;

float largest;

num1=getnumbers();
num2=getnumbers();

largest=findlargest(&num1,&num2);

displaylargest(largest);
```

while(1); // to see the output

```
return 0;
```

}

float getnumbers()

{
    float num;

```
printf("Enter a number\n");

scanf("%2f",&num);

return num;
```

}

float findlargest(float*num1ptr,float*num2ptr)

{

```
float num1;

float num2;

num1 = *num1ptr;

num2 = *num2ptr;

if (num1>num2) {

    return num1;

}
```

else {

```
    return num2;

}
```

}

void displaylargest(float largest) // required changes here

{

```
printf("\nthe largest is %2f ",largest);
```

}